# In which condition the blocking networking i/o is used?

Tags: networking, io, blocking

I have read some lib as libev, all of them use the non-blocking io to handle the network communication. However, in which case the blocking io is used in networking?

Answer (score 1):

For simple programs (e.g. test utility or dedicated client) or when dedicated threads are used.

In the first case there is no point in the extra logic involved with non-blocking I/O, while in the second case the logic is replaced with the logic involving multiple threads where the thread using blocking I/O essentially simulated a dedicated client (or server), this is done at the cost of additional resources for threads and synchronisation, but is often justified, especially when multiple threads are necessary anyway or where threads are cheap in terms of resources.

Non blocking I/O is often used in libraries and other cases where using dedicated threads cannot be justified, for resource, testability or portability concerns. It often boils down to individual taste. The difference often being a matter of style.